# Can I use a variable inside of an input statement?

Tags: python, input, arguments

```
def main():
    total = 0.0
    totalcom = 0.0
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    for x in range(1, 8):
        sales = float(input("Please enter your sales from day", x))

        total += sales
        commission = sales * .1
        totalcom += commission

    print("Your total sales is: ", total)
    print("Your commission is: ", totalcom)


main()
```

My goal is essentially a commission calculator. I am supposed to get the amount of sales per day from the user. However, I would like the user to know what day the information they are entering is for. The error I get says "input expected at most one arguments, got 2". So is there a way to use x in my input statement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [*string formatting*](https://pyformat.info/) to insert the value of `x` in the string:

```
sales = float(input("Please enter your sales from day {}".format(x)))
```

The current value of `x` will be inserted in the placeholder `{}`.